# Looping over a CSV file, attempting to delete particular cells

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, for-loop

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv
fp = open('C:/TemporaryDataFiles/RawData.csv', 'w')
csvFile = csv.writer(fp)


for number, begin, end, test in rows:
    if len(test.split()) <= 100:
        print("Row deleted!")
        print(len(test.split()))
        stock=[]
        begin=[]
        end=[]
        test=[]


    else:
        RowsToWrite= [str(number), str(begin), str(end), str(test)]
        csvFile.writerows(RowsToWrite)
```

I'm trying to iterate over a large table, called rows, which has four subcomponents to it. It has `number` (representing a number of a product), the `begin` time, the `end` time, and a `test` column, which has a description inside of it.

I'm trying to see if `test` has fewer than 100 words in it. If it doesn't, then it goes to the else section of the `if...else` statement, then gets written to the `RawData.csv` file.

This doesn't generate any errors, however, it doesn't give the proper output either. There are a few entries, all under 100 words, which slip through.

I've tried as many iterations as I can think of, and I feel as if I'm missing something basic here.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: what is the data like?

Comment: The number, begin, and end fields are very short-- only a few characters each. The description is much larger-- more frequently than not, over 100 words.

Comment: Have you checked the incorrectly deleted descriptions? Sometimes punctuations and special characters can have spaces before and after them, causing them to be counted as words.

Comment: Yes, I've done that-- they are just standard text/words. Nothing that should trigger something like what you're speaking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think `writerows` is looking for multiple rows, not just one. Do like `RowsToWrite.append([str(number), str(begin), str(end), str(test)])`, and then after the `for` loop use the `csvFile.writerows(RowsToWrite)`. Keep your imports and everything, but the whole for loop would look like this:

```
RowsToWrite = []
for number, begin, end, test in rows:
    if len(test.split()) <= 100:
        print("Row deleted!")
        print(len(test.split()))
        number=''
        begin=''
        end=''
        test=''

    RowsToWrite.append([str(number), str(begin), str(end), str(test)])

csvFile.writerows(RowsToWrite)
```

I guess that the `writerows` method uses commas when writing to the file. Here's the full [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects).

You could also write each row one at a time in the `for` loop (see docs).